# Any reason why this MySQL query wouldn't run?

Tags: php, mysql, cron, truncate

I have the following PHP script setup to run as a cron job every minute:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass");
if (!$con) {
    die("Database error");
}
mysql_query("TRUNCATE TABLE contact_ips");
mysql_close($con);
die();
?>
```

This script is to prevent a contact form being submitted from the same IP address more than once within 1 minute. Therefore, it should clear the contents of the table that submitted the form and it is not doing that.

Could it be my cron command that is working correctly?

Thanks

Comment: You sure you have permissions to TRUNCATE. Have you tried var_dumping mysql_error($con)?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, `mysql_query` is deprecated. Use `mysqli` instead.

Second, it seems like you might want to set a variable to the query, eg `$result = mysqli_query()` so you can do post-processing.

Have you tried adding a `die()` to the mysql query to check that that query is running?

Also, it seems like you haven't selected a DB. Add this after the connection code. `mysql_select_db("databaseName", $con);`

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass");
if (!$con) {
    die("Database error");
}
mysql_select_db("database", $con);
mysql_query("TRUNCATE TABLE contact_ips");
mysql_close($con);
die();
?>
```

Comment: Possibly also mysql_query("TRUNCATE TABLE database.contact_ips"); would work alone.

Comment: yeah, but he didn't have database selected query --> mysql_select_db("database", $con);